# Getting an unspecified syntax error msg 102 at the end of my query, but the query mirrors another that works? Using UNPIVOT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax, unpivot

Title - I'm assuming something is wrong with the UNPIVOT? I just can't figure out what. Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

```
WITH IPEDSData AS
(
    SELECT
         [UnitID]
        ,[Institution Name]
        ,[Peer]
        ,[State abbreviation]
        ,[Sector of institution]
        ,CASE
            WHEN FIELD LIKE '%2018' THEN '2018'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE '%2017' THEN '2017'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE '%2016' THEN '2016'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE '%2015' THEN '2015'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE '%2014' THEN '2014'
            END ReportYear
        ,CASE
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Financial aid cohort%'                                 THEN 'Financial Aid Cohort'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Number of students awarded grant aid%'                 THEN 'Number of Students Awarded Grant Aid'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Percent of students awarded grant aid%'                THEN 'Percent of Students Awarded Grant Aid'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Total amount of grant aid%'                            THEN 'Total Amount of Grant Aid'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Average amount of grant aid%'                          THEN 'Average Amount of Grant Aid'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Number of students awarded Pell grants%'               THEN 'Number of Students Awarded Pell Grants'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Percent of students awarded Pell grants%'              THEN 'Percent of Students Awarded Pell Grants'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Total amount of Pell grant aid awarded%'               THEN 'Total Amount of Pell Grant Aid Awarded'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Average amount of Pell grant aid awarded%%'            THEN 'Average Amount of Pell Grant Aid Awarded'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Number of students awarded federal student loans%'     THEN 'Number of Students Awarded Federal Student Loans'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Percent of students awarded federal student loans%'    THEN 'Percent of Students Awarded Federal Student Loans'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Total amount of federal student loans%'                THEN 'Total Amount of Federal Student Loans'
            WHEN FIELD LIKE 'Average amount of federal student loans%'              THEN 'Average Amount of Federal Student Loans'
            END FinancialAidCategory
        ,Result

    FROM (
         SELECT
             [UnitID]
            ,[Institution Name]
            ,[Peer]
            ,[State abbreviation]
            ,[Sector of institution]
            ,[FIELD]
            ,[Result]

    FROM [data_IPEDS_FinancialAidExtractWithPeers]

    UNPIVOT (
        [Result] FOR 
        [FIELD] IN (
                   [Financial aid cohort 2018]
                  ,[Number of students awarded grant aid 2018]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded grant aid 2018]
                  ,[Total amount of grant aid 2018]
                  ,[Average amount of grant aid 2018]
                  ,[Number of students awarded Pell grants 2018]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded Pell grants 2018]
                  ,[Total amount of Pell grant aid awarded 2018]
                  ,[Average amount Pell grant aid awarded 2018]
                  ,[Number of students awarded federal student loans 2018]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded federal student loans 2018]
                  ,[Total amount of federal student loans awarded 2018]
                  ,[Average amount of federal student loans awarded 2018]
                  ,[Financial aid cohort 2017]
                  ,[Number of students awarded grant aid 2017]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded grant aid 2017]
                  ,[Total amount of grant aid 2017]
                  ,[Average amount of grant aid 2017]
                  ,[Number of students awarded Pell grants 2017]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded Pell grants 2017]
                  ,[Total amount of Pell grant aid awarded 2017]
                  ,[Average amount Pell grant aid awarded 2017]
                  ,[Number of students awarded federal student loans 2017]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded federal student loans 2017]
                  ,[Total amount of federal student loans awarded 2017]
                  ,[Average amount of federal student loans awarded 2017]
                  ,[Financial aid cohort 2016]
                  ,[Number of students awarded grant aid 2016]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded grant aid 2016]
                  ,[Total amount of grant aid 2016]
                  ,[Average amount of grant aid 2016]
                  ,[Number of students awarded Pell grants 2016]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded Pell grants 2016]
                  ,[Total amount of Pell grant aid awarded 2016]
                  ,[Average amount Pell grant aid awarded 2016]
                  ,[Number of students awarded federal student loans 2016]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded federal student loans 2016]
                  ,[Total amount of federal student loans awarded 2016]
                  ,[Average amount of federal student loans awarded 2016]
                  ,[Financial aid cohort 2015]
                  ,[Number of students awarded grant aid 2015]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded grant aid 2015]
                  ,[Total amount of grant aid 2015]
                  ,[Average amount of grant aid 2015]
                  ,[Number of students awarded Pell grants 2015]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded Pell grants 2015]
                  ,[Total amount of Pell grant aid awarded 2015]
                  ,[Average amount Pell grant aid awarded 2015]
                  ,[Number of students awarded federal student loans 2015]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded federal student loans 2015]
                  ,[Total amount of federal student loans awarded 2015]
                  ,[Average amount of federal student loans awarded 2015]
                  ,[Financial aid cohort 2014]
                  ,[Number of students awarded grant aid 2014]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded grant aid 2014]
                  ,[Total amount of grant aid 2014]
                  ,[Average amount of grant aid 2014]
                  ,[Number of students awarded Pell grants 2014]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded Pell grants 2014]
                  ,[Total amount of Pell grant aid awarded 2014]
                  ,[Average amount Pell grant aid awarded 2014]
                  ,[Number of students awarded federal student loans 2014]
                  ,[Percent of students awarded federal student loans 2014]
                  ,[Total amount of federal student loans awarded 2014]
                  ,[Average amount of federal student loans awarded 2014]
                  )
            ) AS U
        ) AS X
)
```

Comment: Added the sql-server tag since the syntax strongly suggests it. Please consider adding yourself the relevant database tag for your next question.

Comment: You have `WITH IPEDSData AS (load of stuff)` and then never `SELECT` from it. The definition of a CTE must be immediately followed by some code that uses it. You can't just define it and leave the statement dangling

Comment: Including the actual error helps us help you as well.

Comment: @Martin Smith that was it - thanks.